# How to downgrade spring boot project from version 2.4 to 2.3?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Can you tell me the steps of downgrading spring boot project from 2.4 to 2.3?

Answer (score 2):

Just change the version name in the pom.xml file from "2.4.1" to "2.3.1.RELEASE".